# Alternative for append()

Tags: python, string, list, function

For the below *add* method:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    self.str_list.append(other)       
    self.count += 1
    return self.str_list
```

How may I rewrite this **without** append?

PS:

1) str_list is an instance variable of type list declared in *init*

2) No inbuilt functions to be used.

Comment: We could use a bit more context for what exactly is being attempted.

Comment: `self.str_list += [ other ] `

Comment: I am adding a new item to str_list. I can use str_list.append() and do this. But I dont want to use built in .append(). Need an alternative

Comment: so... homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting brain teaser, the challenge being adding to a list without using a built-in function. I can only think of one approach:

```
self.str_list = [*self.str_list, other]
```

Other approaches such as `list += [other]` are technically using the built-in method `__add__` so beware for your purpose, whatever it might be.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. One more thing. How do I add a 'space' before adding to the list?

Comment: I guess you mean something like this: `self.str_list = [*self.str_list, " ", other]`

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, please mark as answer. Do you mind if I ask why you wanted to append to a list without using append, I don't see any benefits other a personal challenge?

Comment: Thanks a ton ! Appreciate the help. Was doing a task that required me to append without .append(). Cheers !